# Center div without sliding

Tags: html, css

My URL http://www.ilandeistudio.com/store/

Below the main slider I have some images and categories..How can I center the div "Nelson" and lock it into place so they stay put while zooming/out?

I tried using padding-left and  margin-left but they increase the space in between the categories as well. I just want to slide that entire group into the center...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put those items in a container `div` and give that `div` a `width` and `margin: 0 auto;`

HTML:

```
<div class="nelsonContainer">
  <div class=nelson> 
    <a href="http://www.ilandeistudio.com/store/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=49"> 
      <img src="http://www.ilandeistudio.com/store/image/cache/data/illandei-120x120.png" /> 
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;OUTDOOR
    </a> 
  </div>
  <div class=nelson> 
    <a href="http://www.ilandeistudio.com/store/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=52"> 
  <img src="http://www.ilandeistudio.com/store/image/cache/no_image-120x120.jpg" /> 
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;LIVING   
    </a> 
  </div>
  /* etc. */
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.nelsonContainer {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: I thought of that too, though the problem is that all of the `nelson` divs are floated to stay in line, so they don't occupy the space correctly, and the div doesn't keep them in the center.

Comment: @Nightfirecat make the `.nelsonContainer` div width equal to the number of `.nelson` divs. On your site now: 630px.

Comment: That would work, but it's a rather inflexible solution, and would be difficult to compute if the divs didn't have images, or fixed-max-width objects, such as text.

Comment: Since you're floating the `.nelson` divs, they should already have widths declared. Otherwise, javascript can determine the needed width for `.nelsonContainer`.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap them all in a bigger div, say let's call it `nelson-wrapper`, and then add automatic left and right margins to it.

HTML:

```
<div id="nelson-wrapper">
    <div class="nelson">...</div>
    <div class="nelson">...</div>
    <div class="nelson">...</div>
    <div class="nelson">...</div>
    <div class="nelson">...</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#nelson-wrapper{
    margin: 0 auto; /* Shorthand for 0 top/bottom, auto left/right margins */
}
```

### EDIT:

Actually, since your divs are blocks, not inline, the above will **NOT** work, although the following (which I found at: http://www.impressivewebs.com/center-multiple-divs/) *will* work:

HTML:

```
<div id="nelson-wrapper">
    <div class="nelson">
    <div class="nelson">
    <div class="nelson">
    <div class="nelson">
    <div class="nelson">
    <div class="nelson">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#nelson-wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}
.nelson {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Note: This will not work correctly in Internet Explorer 8-. To get them to behave, unfortunately, the only workaround is either an Internet-Explorer-only hack, or class. The hack works as such:

CSS:

```
.nelson {
    *display: inline;
    *margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
}
```